# Facebook app. How to upload images to the app? Does it have it's own wall or albums?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have Facebook application ready and token, app id, secret. Now I have searched a lot and it seems that I am unable to upload image to App wall or create album for the app.

**What do I have:**
Facebook app with canvas where user can enter data and upload an image(to my PHP script on a server)

**What do I want to do:**
To save the image on my app somewhere from PHP using PHP SDK.

**What's the closest approach I have done:**

1. Googled A LOT
2. I have added login/logout for user so I could upload
       the image to user wall or album but I want to photo to be on the app
       itself so to bypass the user authentification and I need to store
       the image on my app somewhere.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An App itself does not have a place to display images/videos.

You will need to create a Page for the App. To do this, go to [developers.facebook.com/apps](http://developers.facebook.com/apps) and click 'Edit App' in the top-right. In the 'App Details' section, click the button labelled 'Create Facebook Page' and follow the steps. This will create a Page to represent the App. You can then upload images/videos etc. as you would do with any other page.

Or, you could give the *impression* of storing an image on your App by storing the image in a database and recalling it upon demand...

Comment: Thanks! Currently I show the image from the database, however I want it to be displayed in _default_ facebook style(or a lightbox)